# Visual Studio service reference doesn't work, but DataSvcUtil does

Tags: wcf-data-services

I have Visual Studio 2010. If I try to add a service reference to my project I get the error

```
This service cannot be consumed by the current project. Please check if the project target framework supports this service type.
```

But if I run DataSvcUtil on the same endpoint, it works fine.

The thing is that when Visual Studio generates the reference, it generates `Reference.cs`, `Reference.datasvcmap`, and `service.edmx` (I know this because the files used to be there, I deleted the reference to try to re-generate it and am running into this issue). If I use the command line tool, I only get `myfile.cs` (or whatever I named the output file).

Why would this be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a newer version of OData library in your WCF Data Service than the one come with VS2010? If so, you may want to upgrade to VS2012...